# ajax POST for data which contains an array with jQuery and Django

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, post

So I'm looking to take data for checkboxes which have been checked, and I'm pushing these values to an array:

```
var interestedIn = [];

$(":checked").each(function() {
  interestedIn.push($(this).val());
});
```

I'm then passing this array as data to be POSTED by ajax call with some other variables:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "{{ request.path }}",
    data: { 'email': values['email'], 'name': values['name'], 'interestedIn': interestedIn }
})
```

I'm trying to then access the interestedIn variable with a Django views.py file:

```
if request.POST and request.is_ajax():
    interestedin = request.POST.get('interestedIn')
```

When printing the interestedin variable to inspect, this is coming back as None. Does anyone know how you post arrays and variables simultaneously?

Comment: Possibly because you're sending `interestedIn` as an array. How are you deserialising that on the server? Alternatively it may be that the array is out of scope of your AJAX request. It's hard to say with the small snippet of code shown

Comment: No deserialisation server side - I tried client side and it through a few $ errors.

Comment: I don't know Django but, when you say *None*, you mean the variable/array is empty? also, can you verify on server side if `request.POST.get('interestedIn')` is indeed of type `array`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try :

```
data: { 'email': values['email'], 'name': values['name'], 'interestedIn': JSON.stringify(interestedIn)}
```

Comment: This worked - but transports the array as a string to server side so needs a little more manipulation.